# How to create a countdown while the two times are both variables

Tags: javascript, html

When the countdown runs, it is subtracting the two times to get the difference but the problem is, the actual time is increasing so the difference becomes greater and the timer is in reverse.

I am creating a school schedule and the timer needs to show what class you in (achieved) and how long until the next class (stuck) and then what the next class is (achieved).I tried a couple quick fixes, I am not too advanced in programming.

```
function subtime(ctime, atime) {
  //Current time, Array time
  let cArr = ctime.split(":")[1] + "." + ctime.split(":")[2];
  let aArr = atime.split(":")[1] + "." + atime.split(":")[2];
  let ftime = (Math.round((Math.abs(cArr - aArr)) * 100) / 100).toString();
  return ftime.split(".")[0].concat(":", ftime.split(".")[1])
}
```

Basically the function is taking the actual time ( military time) as ctime, and then its taking the military time of when the class ends as atime. The class ending time is already defined by my other function timetell. I would call the function by saying

```
subtime(time, numbers);
```

The function timetell looks like this

```
function timetell(array, i, side) {
  this.array = array[i].split("-")[side].replace(/\s/g, '');
  let side1 = this.array.slice(0, 2) + ":";
  let side2 = this.array.slice(-2);
  let answer = side1.concat(side2);

  return answer.concat(":00");

}
```

The array I am getting the times from is:

```
var times = ["0905 - 0955", "1000 - 1050", "1055 - 1145", "1155 - 1245", "1250 - 1340", "1345 - 1435", "1440 - 1530"];
```

All timetell does is takes one element and separates it and then adds a ":" to show hours and minutes.

Ex:
Input:

```
timetell(times, 1, 1);
```

So it is imputing the array of times, it is imputting 1 for the "1000 - 1050" times. And then 1 for choosing the end of the class. (0 is used for the beginning)

Output:

```
'10:50:00'
```

I expected the output to be how long until the next class but the time till the next class is actually increasing.

Edit: The problem is now the timer doesn't count down from 60 seconds, it counts from 99 to 40. In addition, when it gets to a multiple of 10, (i.e. 10,20,30) it shows the first numbers like the hours then it says undefined.
Examples:
You are in 2nd period, in 20:undefined you will go to third period.
You are in 2nd period, in 20:67 you will go to third period.

The time will go like this:
20:99
20:98
...
20:41
20:undefined
19:99

Comment: Jackson, have you considered rethinking how you store time, maybe working on a minutes from midnight model to store the start/end of each class. Only convert to 'military' when you need to display. This would make your calculations a lot easier.

Comment: Are you open to changing the code etc.

Comment: Tinkered around a bit. Take a look here: https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/ClassSchedule?language=html&folderId=e400299d-b8fa-4f57-a5e1-9b34af28dd4b

Comment: Bibberty, i looked at your code and I am honestly 100% confused. However, I would love to learn. I am all self taught so it is very hard for me to advance in JS but I would love to learn how that code works so i can replicate it for my own stuff. Thanks @Bibberty

Comment: How about I start adding more comments. Maybe create a couple of pages that start more simply.

Comment: @Bibberty could you email me at aikenJa@riversidemilitary.com I have lots of questions and I am limited on time. Thanks!

Comment: @Bibberty I just added an edit to the bottom of the post which explains the current problem, thanks!